# Arrange $n$ people so that some people are never together.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We have $n$ number of people and some pairs given. These pairs of people are never to be together. How to calculate the number of arrangements possible?
e.g we have n=4 and pairs =3 and pairs are
(1,2)
(2,3)
(3,4)
,in this case their are 2 arrangements possible (2 4 1 3) and (3 1 4 2).

Comment: And we are arranging them how? In a line, a circle, a grid, a k-dimensional grid?

Comment: We are arranging them in a line.

Comment: This appears to be taken from a CodeChef programming contest problem that was live at the time: https://www.codechef.com/JAN16/problems/SEAKAM.  (Note how the CodeChef contest promises there will be at most 7 excluded pairs, and [coder promises there will be at most 7 disallowed pairs](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600489/arrange-n-people-so-that-some-people-are-never-together#comment3261613_1600611).)    CodeChef rules prohibit asking others to solve the problem for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically asking for the number of Hamiltonian paths of a given length in an arbitrary finite graph, namely the one with vertices $1,\ldots,n$, and as edges all pairs that are not forbidden. Given the generality of the problem, it would be naive to assume there exists a simple formula that gives the answer, using for instance only the *number* of available edges; clearly the details of the graph do matter a lot. So you are asking too much.

Comment: Here's an illustration, since I found it hard to see this initially. Suppose we're seating $4$ people, and we have disallowed the pairs $\{(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)\}$ -- i.e. the first person cannot be next to *anyone*, so no arrangements exist. If we had chosen some other three pairs, such as $\{(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)\}$, then for example the arrangement $2413$ would exist.

Comment: Here maximum pairs which are disallowed are 7.